# Full Text not indexing varbinary column (with html)

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

I have a table with HTML data, that I want to search using the Full Text Index via an html-filter

So I created an index:

```
CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG myCatalog AS DEFAULT

CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON myTable (Body TYPE COLUMN Filetype)
                        KEY INDEX PK_myTable
```

`Body` is a `varbinary(max)` column with HTML. The `Filetype` column is a computed column returns `.html`.

No results are being returned.

I verified that `.html` filter is installed. FullText index is also installed properly and *works fine* if I convert the column to `nvarchar` and create just a "plain text" index (not html).

No errors in the SQL log or FTS log.

**The keywords table is just empty!**

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.dm_fts_index_keywords
(DB_ID('myDatabase'), OBJECT_ID('myTable'))
```

All it returns is "END OF FILE" symbol.

[image]

It says "document count 35" which mean the documents were processed, but no keywords were extracted.

PS. I have SQL Server **Express** Edition 2012 (with all advanced features including full text). Can this be the reason? But again, the "plain" full text search works just fine!

PPS. Asked my coworker to test this on SQL Express 2016 - same result... Tried on our production server "Enterprise" edition - same.

### UPDATE

OK it turns out the full text index DOES NOT SUPPORT UNICODE!! in varbinary columns. When I converted the column to non-unicode (by converting it to `nvarchar` then to `varchar` and then back to `varbinary`) It started working.

Anyone knows any workarounds?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OK, so it turns out fulltext index DOES support unicode data in `varbinary` but pay attention to this:

**If your `varbinary` column is created from `Nvarchar` be sure to include the `0xFFFE` unicode signature at the beginning**

For example, I'm using a computed column for full text index, so I had to change my computed column to this:

```
alter table myTable
add FTS_Body as 0xFFFE + (CAST(HtmlBody as VARBINARY(MAX)))
--HtmlBody is my nvarchar column that contains html
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this question!  It explained why I was getting nothing from my full text index.

Comment: I have no idea how you figured this out, but it absolutely works. Should be in the official documentation.